# Using ng-bind-html with a custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I need to dynamically load a one of a few custom directives into a view, and have come across the `ng-bind-html` directive

Can I pass in a string representation of my directive as it would be used in markup?

So for example, say in the controller I have

```
vm.dir= '<my-directive data="someData" click-handler="vm.aClickHandler"></my-directive>';
```

I'd like to be able to get this to appear like so

This does not work for me, I don't see the directive markup in the DOM, just the div with the ng-bind-html attribute.

If I use a simple HTML string like `<b>Hi!</b>` then this gets rendered fine in my view.

I want to be able to dynamically add directive markup into my view markup based on logic in the controller, will ng-bind-html help me here?

Comment: *"will ng-bind-html help me here"* ... no, it doesn't compile directives. What is use case? Sounds like you aren't constructing model view relationship as it should be done

Answer (score 0):

[ng-bind-template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindTemplate) may do what you want.

> The ngBindTemplate directive specifies that the element text content should be replaced with the interpolation of the template in the ngBindTemplate attribute. Unlike ngBind, the ngBindTemplate can contain multiple {{ }} expressions. This directive is needed since some HTML elements (such as TITLE and OPTION) cannot contain SPAN elements.

You could also just use ng-include to point to a partial file or the contents of a [script tag](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script).

[Here](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/) is another way you could accomplish this.